# I am getting error when running Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I am getting error like find: '/opt/ibm/wlp/bin': No such file or directory when building a docker image

```
    FROM centos:latest
    RUN yum -y install wget unzip;
    ENV JAVA_VERSION 1.8.0_sr5fp7
    ENV LIBERTY_VERSION 17.0.0_04
    RUN export BASE_URL="https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/systems/cloud/runtimes/java/meta/sdk/linux/x86_64/index.yml"; \
        wget -q -U UA_IBM_JAVA_Docker -O /tmp/index.yml ${BASE_URL}; \
        JAVA_URL=$(cat /tmp/index.yml | sed -n '/'${JAVA_VERSION}'/{n;p}' | sed -n 's/\s*uri:\s//p' | tr -d '\r'); \
        wget -q -U UA_IBM_JAVA_Docker -O /tmp/ibm-java.bin ${JAVA_URL}; \
        echo "INSTALLER_UI=silent" > /tmp/response.properties; \
        echo "USER_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/ibm/java" >> /tmp/response.properties; \
        echo "LICENSE_ACCEPTED=TRUE" >> /tmp/response.properties; \
        mkdir -p /opt/ibm; \
        chmod +x /tmp/ibm-java.bin; \
        /tmp/ibm-java.bin -i silent -f /tmp/response.properties; \
        rm -f /tmp/response.properties; \
        rm -f /tmp/index.yml; \
        rm -f /tmp/ibm-java.bin; \
        cd /opt/ibm/java/jre/lib; \
        rm -rf icc; 
        ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/ibm/java/jre \
        PATH=/opt/ibm/java/jre/bin:$PATH
    RUN echo ${JAVA_HOME}; \
        echo ${PATH}; 
    RUN export LIB_BASE_URL="https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/downloads/wlp/index.yml"; \
        wget -q -U UA-IBM-WebSphere-Liberty-Docker -O /tmp/index.yml ${LIB_BASE_URL}; \
        LIBERTY_URL=$(cat /tmp/index.yml | sed -n '/'${LIBERTY_VERSION}'/{n;p}' | sed -n 's/\s*uri:\s//p' | tr -d '\r'); \
        wget $LIBERTY_URL -U UA-IBM-WebSphere-Liberty-Docker -O /tmp/wlp.zip; \
        unzip -q /tmp/wlp.zip -d /opt/ibm; \
        rm -f /tmp/wlp.zip;
    ENV PATH=/opt/ibm/wlp/bin:$PATH
    LABEL "ProductID"="fbf6a96d49214c0abc6a3bc5da6e48cd"; \
    "ProductName"="WebSphere Application Server Liberty"; \
    "ProductVersion"="17.0.0.4";
    RUN find /opt/ibm/wlp/bin -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;
    RUN /opt/ibm/wlp/bin/server create;
    ADD server.xml /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml
    RUN /opt/ibm/wlp/bin/installUtility install --acceptLicense webProfile-7.0 localConnector-1.0 jndi-1.0 adminCenter-1.0 appSecurity-2.0 concurrent-1.0 \
        ldapRegistry-3.0 javaMail-1.5 jdbc-4.1 jaxrs-2.0 jpa-2.1 ssl-1.0 webCache-1.0;

    ADD lib /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/lib
    ADD apps /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps
    ADD resources /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/resources
    ADD server.xml /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml

    EXPOSE 9080
    EXPOSE 9043

    CMD ["/opt/ibm/wlp/bin/server", "run", "defaultServer"]
```

getting below message : The command '/bin/sh -c find /opt/ibm/wlp/bin -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;' returned a non-zero code: 1
not sure what is wrong ,please help

Comment: Where, in all the steps prior to `ENV PATH=/opt/ibm/wlp/bin:$PATH`, do you create the `/opt/ibm/wlp/bin` directory?

Comment: I am new to docker .so do i need to create the directory first before ENV PATH=/opt/ibm/wlp/bin:$PATH ? for others it is not throwing this error

Comment: The error message is pretty clear... you've asked `find` to search `/opt/ibm/wlp/bin` for files but that directory doesn't exist. Are you expecting one of the previous steps (eg `/tmp/ibm-java.bin -i silent -f /tmp/response.properties`) to create it?

Comment: found the issue , it was due to version issue for Liberty server , changed the docker file with latest version of Liberty Server, it is working fine now